# The name 'String' is defined in the libraries 'dart:core'. Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My Flutter project was working well. But today when I opened, it is showing the following error

```
The name 'String' is defined in the libraries 'dart:core', 'package:courses/createNewCourse.dart' and 'package:courses/dashboard.dart'.
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.
```

This error appears in all the files where `String` is used.

I updated dart and flutter today.

Comment: Are there another class or global variable in "package:courses/createNewCourse.dart" with the name String?

Comment: It's possible to make typos which makes it look to the compiler like you are declaring something named `String`. Check that the `createNewCourse.dart` file doesn't do that accidentally. In your IDE, you can perhaps go into `createNewCourse.dart` and write `String` and do a "go to definition" to see where it thinks that `String` is declared.

Comment: When I click ```Go to Definition``` it shows, No definitions Found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from IDE, as the dart is updated, we can now use extensions. As I used the String extension to capitalize the first word, I got this IDE error. Once I deleted the extension the error is gone. Though the IDE was showing few errors, app build was working fine.